# Getting infinite loop in C++ while-loop, why is this happening?

Tags: c++, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

 int val1=0, val2=0;
 bool a=true;
 
 while(a)
 {
  cout << "Enter 2 numbers: " << endl;
  cin >> val1 >> val2;
  if( val1=='|' || val2=='|' ) a=false; //terminate loop
  else cout << val1 << " " << val2 << endl;
 }

}
```

Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them.
Exit the program when a terminating '|' is entered.

This is what i want to program, code works well until entering non digit charachter. even '|' makes it to go in infinite loop. I just want to know why? Could not figure it out

Comment: I'd suggest adding a bit of space to your code to make it more readable, as in `if (val1 == '|' || val2 == '|')`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: You're asking for two *numbers* and testing for...vertical bar characters? Remember `'|'` is just 124 as far as the machine is concerned.

Comment: What is the input format you're trying to handle? As structured this takes only numerical values separated by a space, like `20 2` or `5 -1` but nothing else.

Comment: problem was in the input, i was terminating programs by entering a charachter(for int types). so i thought it will terminate in this too.

Comment: Please don't edit solutions into questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cin >> val1 >> val2;
```

The `>>` overload for a `std::istream` expects to read an integer number on input. An integer number is, well, an integer number. It would be 0, 1, -5, or 42. These are integer numbers.

The `|` character is not an integer number.

> I just want to know why?

Because when an input operation fails, in this manner, the input stream is set to a failed state. When an input stream is in a failed state all further attempted formatted input operations immediately fail without setting the target of the formatted input operation.

So, entering `|` on input leaves `val1` and `val2` unchanged, and the stream in a failed state. The input stream remains in a failed state, and the same thing happens on the next iteration of the loop.

And that's why you get an infinite loop.

```
if( val1=='|' || val2=='|' )
```

This line does not do what you think it does. `val1` and `val2` are integers. A character is also an integer, interpreted as an ASCII code, so what this really does is compare `val1` and `val2` to the code for the Ascii character `|`. But, for the reasons explained above, inputting `|` does not set an `int` value to its ASCII code, `>>` does not work this way. It leaves the input stream in a failed state, `>>` on an `int` expects to read an actual, real number, something that would correspond to the number of fingers you have, if you had a corresponding number of fingers (or short the requisite amount in case of a 0 or a negative number, I suppose...)